# Having problem running flutter app on simulator

Tags: flutter, xcode, cocoapods

I have been facing this problem for almost a day now. Its getting really frustrating. I have already deleted and reinstalled xcode but I think the problem is with vscode or cocoapods because the podfile isnt showing on the ios directory. What to do? [[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ppRm.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6uDuu.jpg)

I uninstalled and reinstalled all the apps involved but nothing to the good